# Python Pandas nested MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I try to read get a nested mongodb result into a pandas dataframe.

The data looks like this.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5911b9cebb56c016794d45a4"),
"crawlat" : "2017-05-09 14:45",
"traffic" : [ 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494338401",
        "organic" : 53
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494342001",
        "organic" : 64
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494345601",
        "organic" : 74
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494349201",
        "organic" : 78
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494352801",
        "organic" : 80
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494356401",
        "organic" : 88
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494360001",
        "organic" : 91
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494363601",
        "organic" : 92
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp" : "1494367201",
        "organic" : 94
    }
]
```

}

The traffic array contains 48 entries for every result.

Im just interested in the values of "organic" ordered in the order of the array.

I start with

```
con = pymongo.MongoClient(['...:27017'])
collsitemap = con.sitemap.newssitemap
sitemapsdata = collsitemap.find({'traffic':{'$size':48}})
```

I did some cleanup used json_normalize and

```
dfsitemap = dfsitemap['traffic'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Now the result look like this

[image]

But i need a table with just the organic values. How can i clean this up?

Comment: What are the two dimensions in your data frame?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your data frame with the `from_records` constructor, which allows you to specify columns to include or exclude:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(sitemapsdata['traffic'], exclude=['timestamp'])
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: OK thanks i get an error: TypeError: Argument 'rows' has incorrect type (expected list, got Series) Traffic is an array as you can see above.

Comment: Sorry that's a variable typo. The argument to `from_records` is a list of dicts (in your case the value of `traffic`). I've updated the answer.

Comment: Now i get: TypeError: index 'traffic' cannot be applied to Cursor instances
The find will return multiple rows.